# Upgrading drupal 8 beta3 to beta4 table user__roles not exists

Tags: 8, updating, upgrading

When I upgrade my drupal site to beta4 release, it says that table user__roles is not exits.

It's look like that new beta version alter table name from **users_roles** to **user__roles**. how is possible to apply this change (*How is possible to migrate schema of drupal to latest version*).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no upgrade path yet.

You could try to alter the table manually, or copy it from a new install, but you will very likely run into other issues as well.

Comment: Thanks @Berdir for your answer, is there any straight forward way for importing nodes from oldest beta to new one!?

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, so, beta version is backward incompatible, is it true!?